# Is EC2 t3.micro created by ECS cluster eligible for free tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I know that you have free 750 hours if you created ec2 t3.micro instance. But what if you created ECS cluster and choosed t3.micro type for tasks. Will that still be free if you have only one ec2?

I tried to look for explanation on aws page and googled it, but have not found clear explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using the EC2 Launch Type in ECS, then you are billed in the same way as if you were to spin-up an EC2 instance directly via EC2. This means that a t3.micro will have the 750 free hours as per the Free Tier.

The ECS documentation (however, slightly unclear) states:

```
When using Amazon ECS on AWS Outposts, the pricing follows the same model that's used when you use Amazon EC2 directly.
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html